# Get a Graphical Map in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, maps

I have an activity called LocationTest and in my application that get the latitude and longitude and it is working properly.This activity includes a button that take us to another activity that called MapLocation that shows graphically the location on a map.But when I click the app will stop working.I will post the code of the 2 activities if somebody can help plz.I think the error is in the second activity

LocationTest Activity

```
public class LocationTest extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener  {


private FusedLocationProviderApi locationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
public final static int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND=1000;
public final static int MINUTE = 60*MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
private double longitude=0;
private double latitude=0;
private TextView lblLong;
private TextView lblLat;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_test);

    //this here is for the map
    Button mapBtn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.mapBtn);
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    mapBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(LocationTest.this,MapLocation.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    locationRequest= new LocationRequest();
    /*locationRequest.setInterval(MINUTE);*/
    locationRequest.setInterval((MINUTE));
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(15 * MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    lblLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblLong);
    lblLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lblLat);



}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(googleApiClient.isConnected()){
        requestLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)  {
    requestLocationUpdates();
}

    private void requestLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);

    }

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Your Location Has Been Set: " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    latitude = location.getLatitude();
    lblLong.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
    lblLat.setText(Double.toString(latitude));


}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

MapLocation Activity

```
public class MapLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements  LocationListener{


GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        finish();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_location);
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
            (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
    googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
        return false;
    }
}


}
```

Comment: I'm new to mobile development, I don't know what's a crash log. Can you help me with the code please.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show a map in your app, you will need the following steps:

**1) Get you API key from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/ and set your permissions like this in your manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Your package name" >
    ...
    <!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.arshad.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        ...

        <!-- Maps API -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Replace with your API key" />

        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**2) Here is an example using fragments:**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import R;

public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String ARG_LONGITUDE = "longitude";
    private static final String ARG_LATITUDE = "latitude";
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MapFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private String mLongitude;
    private String mLatitude;

    //Google maps parameters initialization
    static LatLng location = new LatLng(21, 57);

    public static MapFragment newInstance(String longitude, String latitude) {
        MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_LONGITUDE, longitude);
        args.putString(ARG_LATITUDE, latitude);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            //Get lattitude and longitude
            mLongitude = getArguments().getString(ARG_LONGITUDE);
            mLatitude = getArguments().getString(ARG_LATITUDE);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Long = " + mLongitude + " lat = " + mLatitude);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.rl_map_container, mapFragment).commit();

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        //Setting the position of camera in the important location
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(Double.valueOf(mLatitude), Double.valueOf(mLongitude)), 17));
        //Adding a marker with customized icon
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_<Your icon name>))
                .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f) // Anchors the marker on the bottom left
                .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(mLatitude), Double.valueOf(mLongitude))));

        // MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN, MAP_TYPE_HYBRID and MAP_TYPE_NONE
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


    }
}
```

**3) Make your layout like this:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MapFragment"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, you can get more information in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/